# React: How to get data from Axios, not Promise?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get data from a link but all I get is a Promise.
Here is my example code:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const url = `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile2?symbol=GME&token=c6a500qad3idi8g5o2v0`;

  const fetchData = async (u) => {
    return await axios.get(u).then((res) => res.data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => console.log(fetchData(url))}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't know which part of the code is wrong that it keeps giving out the Promise like the photo here:

[image]

Please help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
  import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const url = `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile2?symbol=GME&token=c6a500qad3idi8g5o2v0`;
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const fetchData = async (u) => {
    return await axios.get(u).then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
      console.log(res.data.name);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => fetchData(url)}>click me</button>
      Name :{data?.name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow the trick is to `useState` right there inside the `then`. I got it now. Thank you so much!!